# Separating mesh into different parts breaks shape keys

Tags: mesh

I am using a 3D head model I found online. The model comes with many shape keys on the face, which work great.

However, the model has the eyebrows included inside the 'Head' mesh. I wanted to separate the eyebrows into a new mesh, so I imported the model into Blender and selected the eyebrows and separated them into a different mesh.

Unfortunately after that, when I play with the shape key values, a lot of the shape keys no longer work. Especially the shape keys that involve eyebrow movement.

Would there be a way to separate the eyebrows into a new mesh, but to keep the shape keys working?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blendshapes"? That's not an expression I've heard before.

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean "Shape Keys".  I believe they are also referred to as blendshapes in other software (Unity).